# SQLITE query to join two of same tables with different conditions

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sqlite

I have this SQL table called `messages` which has the details like following;

```
id, sender, recipient, message, timestamp

"1","10204456572654160","10208819391147662","Hi.. : What are you up to?","1459541723279"
"2","10204456572654160","10208819391147662","Got my test message?","1459541749818"
"3","10208819391147662","10204456572654160","This is my message","1459611679108"
"4","10208819391147662","10204456572654160","And another message","1459611735455"
"5","10204456572654160","10208819391147662","And I reply like this","1459611758570"
"6","10153775515332771","10208819391147662","It's me.. Syco !!","1459611900348"
"7","10153775515332771","10208819391147662","You there?","1459611900350"
"8","10208819391147662","10153775515332771","Yes.. What's upp..","1459611900380"
"9","10204464403169266","10208819391147662","How're you doin?","1459612000666"
```

Now, I want to pass a value to my function `e.g. 10208819391147662` and to show result like following columns;

1. Unique value of `sender/recipient` which is **NOT** `10208819391147662`
2. The last `message` between `sender/recipient` which is **NOT** `10208819391147662` **AND** `sender/recipient` which is `10208819391147662`.
3. The `timestamp` of the 2nd (message).

In order to achieve the following, I have this sql;

```
SELECT s1.*, max(c2.message), max(c2.timestamp)
FROM (
    SELECT sender as username 
    FROM messages
    WHERE sender <> '10208819391147662'
    UNION
    SELECT recipient as username 
    FROM messages
    WHERE recipient <> '10208819391147662'
) s1
LEFT JOIN messages c2 ON (s1.username = c2.sender OR s1.username = c2.recipient)
GROUP BY s1.username
```

I have sucessfully extracted the `1st column` by using `UNION`. But with no lucks on the 2nd and 3rd by using `MAX` and `Group by` clause.

My final expected result should be;

```
username, message, timestamp

"10204456572654160","And I reply like this","1459611758570"
"10153775515332771","Yes.. What's upp..","1459611900380"
"10204464403169266","How're you doin?","1459612000666"
```

And here's my [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3edec/6) so far. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: You need to reword the question. Some of it is very hard to read ie `The last message between sender/recipient which is NOT 10208819391147662 AND sender/recipient which is 10208819391147662.` Can you write  a single paragraph explain what the data is and what you are trying to do ie give the requirement not a partial implementation.

Comment: Please use tags properly. mysql<>sql-server<>sqlite

Comment: What would you need MAX for?

Comment: @CL. I want to get the last `message` and `timestamp` between the `sender/recipient` and `10208819391147662`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, finally this is my final SQL which accomplishes what I want.

```
SELECT c2.id, s1.username, c2.message, max(c2.timestamp)
FROM (
    SELECT sender as username 
    FROM messages
    WHERE sender <> '10208819391147662'
    UNION
    SELECT recipient as username 
    FROM messages
    WHERE recipient <> '10208819391147662'
) s1
LEFT JOIN messages c2 ON (s1.username = c2.sender OR s1.username = c2.recipient)
GROUP BY s1.username
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

But somehow, in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/3edec/1), This doesn't work as expected in `MYSQL` but yet it works well in `SQLITE`.

Comment: SQLite guarantees that other columns come from the same row that matches the MAX(). MySQL returns column values from some random row; other databases forbid this altogether.